# Rertofit POST с параметром

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

Каким образом я могу описать интерфейс для такого POST запроса?

http://validate.jsontest.com/?json={"key":"value"}

Я разрыл кучу всего, но не получилось.

```
@FormUrlEncoded 
    @POST("http://validate.jsontest.com/")
    Call<Map<String,String>>getValidation(@Field("?json=")  String body);
```

Comment: Это у вас get запрос написан. `getValidation(@Query("json") String body)`

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: GET вполне неплохо отрабатывает